# Does "= default" allow out-of-line implementations?

Tags: c++, c++11

Usually I see the `= default` syntax used in the header. My understanding is that this is the same as if the functions are explicitly implemented in the header, see `Foo` below.

## Foo.h

```
#pragma once

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(const Foo& other) = default;
};
```

Purely out of curiosity, can the `= default` be used in the source files as follows?

## Bar.h

```
#pragma once

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();

    Bar(const Bar& other);
};
```

## Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar() = default;

Bar::Bar(const Bar&) = default;
```

As far as I know this is equivalent to explicitly implementing the functions in the cpp file.

The above `Bar` example compiles with `gcc-5.1` but does the standard allow for this usage?

*As an aside*, are there any benefits to using `= default` in the source file versus the header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is legal.  From **[dcl.fct.def.default]**

> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4, 12.8), which might mean defining them as deleted. **A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly defaulted;** if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the program is ill-formed.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

And then they go on to detail you exact scenario with

> ```
> struct nontrivial1 {
>   nontrivial1();
> };
> nontrivial1::nontrivial1() = default; // not first declaration
> ```

So as long as the function is not implicitly marked as deleted then the function will be defined where you explicitly default it.

> As an aside, are there any benefits to using `= default` in the source file versus the header?

The only "advantage" I can see it it allows existing code bases to change their cpp files to use modern techniques without having to change the header file.  There is even a note in the standard:

> *Note:* Declaring a function as defaulted after its first declaration can provide efficient execution and concise definition while enabling a stable binary interface to an evolving code base.

Comment: Interesting. A _user-provided explicitly defaulted function_ sounds paradoxical to me, what with juxtaposing _defaulted_ and _user-provided_, but what can ya do. It makes its own kind of sense, which is about as much as we can hope for. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

One potential usage of defaulting in the source file instead of the header is to use the pimpl idiom with `unique_ptr`. It requires a complete type for construction and destruction, so you can't define those special members in the header. You'd have to do:

Foo.h

```
struct Foo { 
    struct Impl;
    unique_ptr<Impl> p;
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
// Foo::Impl definition here

// now Impl isn't incomplete
Foo::Foo() = default;
Foo::~Foo() = default;
```

Comment: Ah, so that'll be what the hopelessly vague note in the Standard (as quoted in the accepted answer) was trying to say!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, special member functions may be defaulted "out of line"; the compiler will generate the correct code and it will work as expected.

In fact, there is a rule relating to special members not being defaulted on first declaration, they are then considered user provided (and hence non-trivial).

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the program is ill-formed.

[Link here [dcl.fct.def.default]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#5). With the following example detailing your situation;

> ```
> struct nontrivial1 {
>   nontrivial1();
> };
> nontrivial1::nontrivial1() = default; // not first declaration
> ```

Its usefulness lies in what it does, it provides the default implementation, but not at the point of declaration, thus making it *user-provided*. As noted, this is useful when dealing with an as-yet incomplete type, such as when using the pimpl idiom. It could also be used to mark your type as non-trivial, thus prohibiting its use in code that requires a trivial type (e.g. [`std::is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial)).

Comment: mentioning triviality and application to incomplete types such as pimpl gives this a grounding in the real world => +1

Answer (score 1):

There is a small change in the behaviour. Other TU than `Bar.cpp` can't see that they are defaulted because they only see the header. So putting default in the cpp will make your class not trivially assignable and not trivially constructible.

There are some case that you want to do this: if your class hold a `unique_ptr` to an incomplete type, it's a good practice to default the destructor in the cpp, because if you don't, classes that uses yours will be required the incomplete type's destructor to be visible.

Comment: What's the significance of being trivially constructible or lack thereof?

Comment: I think the compiler or library writer can do optimization when classes are trivially constructible. I'm not sure at 100% though.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing in source file,
the methods are no longer *defaulted* but *user provided*.

Comment: @Ahmet If you default it out of line, then it's not defaulted on its first declaration. Jarod is correct.

Comment: Oh yeah,I missed the first 'and' there :)